# Which of the following sentences is considered correct?

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement

"The only **thing we lacks** is pride."

"The only **thing we lack** is pride."

Comment: Which do you think is correct - and why?

Comment: **Hint:** The verb should agree with *we*, not *thing*. I believe that's why you are confused.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a duplicate, which I imagine exists. If we could find one or two, that would be helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Riya, if you could [edit] your post to include more details, like why you are confused, or why you think one is correct, that will help clarify your problem. It might also prevent close votes and down votes. Also, try searching our site. We likely have related or duplicate posts. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips.

Answer (score 0):

"We lack" because **the only thing** is an object and the subject is **we.**

Answer (score 0):

The main sentence here is "The only thing is pride."  It then has a subordinate clause "we lack" that modifies thing.  Because the subject of the clause is "we," it takes "lack."